# Iterating through a column

Tags: python, selenium

[image]I'm trying to get all the hrefs for every player. I can get one but I need to iterate through the column and get all the hrefs. How do I do that?

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

browser = webdriver.Chrome("/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/chromedriver.exe") 

browser = webdriver.Chrome("/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/chromedriver.exe")

browser.get("https://rotogrinders.com/projected-stats/mlb-hitter?site=fanduel")

# Wait 20 seconds for page to load
timeout = 20
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'player-popup')))
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
    browser.quit()

# find_elements_by_xpath returns an array of selenium objects.
players_element = browser.find_element_by_class_name('player-popup')
links = browser.find_element_by_class_name('player-popup')
print(links.get_attribute("href"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all players:

```
players = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.player')
```

Note the trailing `s` in `elements`.

Now iterate over them, and get the `href` attribute of the `a` tag you need (from your example it seems to be the one with the `player-popup` class):

```
for player in players:
    link = player.find_element_by_class_name('player-popup')
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

OTOH, if the `player-popup` classes contain the players you want, you can do:

```
players = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('.player-popup')
for player in players:
    print(player.get_attribute('href'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CSS` selector which is much faster to fetch all the expected values.I have pulled all the values in a list so that you can use it later for web scraping.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome("/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("https://rotogrinders.com/projected-stats/mlb-hitter?site=fanduel")
print(len(WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.player a.player-popup')))))
players_url=[a.get_attribute('href') for a in WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.player a.player-popup')))]
print(players_url)
```

### Output:

```
Total links count:476

['https://rotogrinders.com/players/eric-thames-11223', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/matthew-beaty-814626', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/colin-moran-17459', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/daniel-palka-36198', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/russell-martin-10272', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/victor-reyes-41726', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/nicky-lopez-1017714', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jake-marisnick-15122', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/eugenio-suarez-15566', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/kyle-schwarber-18884', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/howie-kendrick-14586', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/max-muncy-17648', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/phillip-ervin-36149', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/austin-nola-16499', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jose-martinez-15262', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/rio-ruiz-17689', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/brian-dozier-13440', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/francisco-mejia-36196', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/keston-hiura-1024184', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/ian-desmond-10487', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/ryan-braun-10542', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/chris-davis-18804', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mitch-garver-36197', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jonathan-schoop-15625', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/joc-pederson-16129', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/yasmani-grandal-13483', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/franmil-reyes-309161', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/teoscar-hernandez-17884', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jake-lamb-16087', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/tyler-white-34734', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/victor-robles-37585', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/c.j.-cron-17712', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/vladimir-guerrero%20jr-967469', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/corey-dickerson-15864', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/nelson-cruz-10512', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/ji-man-choi-17544', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-moustakas-11315', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/robinson-chirinos-14646', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/tommy-la%20stella-18016', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/dominic-smith-37481', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/alex-gordon-10580', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/justin-smoak-10351', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jordan-luplow-37428', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/ryan-zimmerman-10429', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/harrison-bader-37410', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/alex-verdugo-37543', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/chris-iannetta-10279', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/billy-hamilton-15551', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jose-iglesias-11198', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jake-cave-17731', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/justin-bour-15657', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/hunter-renfroe-17857', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/anthony-rizzo-11311', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/christian-yelich-15181', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/joey-wendle-17468', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/kole-calhoun-13472', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/chris-taylor-16227', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/j.t.-realmuto-18004', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/bobby-bradley-813903', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mark-reynolds-10436', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/asdrubal-cabrera-10483', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/bryan-reynolds-956689', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/cody-bellinger-36727', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jarrod-dyson-10614', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/randal-grichuk-15357', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/rougned-odor-15483', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/dylan-moore-814186', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/brandon-belt-10344', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/niko-goodrum-15821', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-trout-11380', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/starlin-castro-10482', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/alex-dickerson-16347', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/miguel-cabrera-10323', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jon-jay-10610', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/neil-walker-10376', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/addison-russell-16146', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/miguel-sano-16338', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/matt-olson-17887', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/dwight-smith%20jr.-36766', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/tim-beckham-14725', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/willie-calhoun-37586', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/brandon-lowe-481940', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/yulieski-gurriel-35357', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/nick-senzel-873104', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/trea-turner-21824', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/chance-sisco-37544', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/robinson-cano-10370', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/lourdes-gurriel-36142', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/nick-castellanos-14698', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/adam-jones-10551', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/stevie-wilkerson-402569', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/anthony-santander-36502', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/patrick-valaika-17664', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/alex-bregman-35330', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/javier-baez-15811', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/fernando-tatis-894407', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/yadier-molina-10270', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/eric-hosmer-11184', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/tom-murphy-17578', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jeimer-candelario-15812', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/josh-bell-14928', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/robbie-grossman-14622', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/andrelton-simmons-13484', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/joey-votto-10325', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/justin-turner-11113', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/myles-straw-538921', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/matt-carpenter-11296', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/manuel-margot-17933', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jason-heyward-10513', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/buster-posey-10262', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/ramon-laureano-38057', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/trey-mancini-17649', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/paul-dejong-36796', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/johan-camargo-36167', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/kurt-suzuki-10265', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/christin-stewart-530985', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/austin-meadows-38016', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/evan-longoria-10426', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/brandon-crawford-11266', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/manny-machado-13534', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/guillermo-heredia-34659', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/adam-frazier-17869', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jorge-soler-16119', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jorge-polanco-15820', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/albert-almora-16148', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/greg-garcia-16078', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/curt-casali-15040', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/nolan-arenado-14626', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/yasiel-puig-15854', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/domingo-santana-16283', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/shohei-ohtani-41843', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/george-springer-15035', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/paul-goldschmidt-11431', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/harold-ramirez-17826', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/scott-kingery-183328', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/kris-bryant-17540', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/todd-frazier-11254', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/anthony-rendon-14613', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/hanser-alberto-16145', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/yoan-moncada-35706', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/eloy-jimenez-37999', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/khris-davis-14582', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jose-abreu-17437', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/humberto-arteaga-1114252', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jonathan-villar-14916', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/yolmer-sanchez-15508', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jorge-alfaro-16472', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/oscar-mercado-38019', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/charlie-blackmon-11306', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/garrett-hampson-464348', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/carlos-santana-10261', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/cheslor-cuthbert-16251', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/nomar-mazara-16207', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/hunter-dozier-17851', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/freddy-galvis-13388', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/francisco-lindor-15953', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/scooter-gennett-15252', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/luis-arraez-814065', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jose-altuve-11406', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/starling-marte-13518', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/shin-soo-choo-10516', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/brian-anderson-36571', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/michael-conforto-21540', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/whit-merrifield-15652', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/justin-upton-10554', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/carson-kelly-16203', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/joey-gallo-16199', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/ketel-marte-15782', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/marcus-semien-15633', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/willy-adames-36176', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/miguel-rojas-16128', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/ronald-guzman-17798', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/willson-contreras-34682', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/lorenzo-cain-13286', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mallex-smith-17609', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/harold-castro-546217', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/nick-ahmed-15528', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/eric-sogard-11389', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-zunino-15860', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/brandon-dixon-332266', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/stephen-piscotty-16136', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/leury-garcia-14562', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/rhys-hoskins-37480', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/kevin-newman-498052', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/tommy-pham-16460', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/kevin-pillar-16168', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/charlie-tilson-16202', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/bobby-wilson-10311', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/david-dahl-17878', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/elias-diaz-22662', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/matt-chapman-37180', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/roberto-perez-15356', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/luis-rengifo-36539', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/garrett-cooper-17704', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jonathan-lucroy-11064', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/danny-jansen-38031', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-yastrzemski-1052567', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jurickson-profar-13551', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/maikel-franco-17482', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jeff-mcneil-470026', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/bryce-harper-13392', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/max-kepler-15798', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jean-segura-13516', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/j.t.-riddle-17839', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/juan-soto-326703', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/cavan-biggio-1049725', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/adam-eaton-13612', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/kolten-wong-15191', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/david-peralta-17693', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/pete-alonso-894408', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/marcell-ozuna-14629', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/austin-riley-1023422', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/eduardo-escobar-11507', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/ozzie-albies-37435', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/martin-maldonado-11487', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mac-williamson-16321', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/josh-phegley-15086', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/nick-markakis-10533', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/daniel-vogelbach-16151', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jay-bruce-10536', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/josh-donaldson-11152', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/yandy-diaz-17802', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/elvis-andrus-10476', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/michael-brantley-10564', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/j.p.-crawford-37557', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/cesar-hernandez-15036', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jason-kipnis-11408', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/freddie-freeman-10345', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jakob-bauers-38036', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/james-mccann-14700', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/zack-collins-1106987', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/ronald-acuna-262363', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/joe-panik-14880', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/orlando-arcia-16290', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/brian-mccann-10264', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/amed-rosario-36162', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/tomas-nido-36161', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jeff-mathis-10290', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/chris-archer-17449', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/antonio-senzatela-34707', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jhoulys-chacin-10924', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jose-berrios-35029', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/antonio-senzatela-34707', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/anibal-sanchez-10997', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/sean-reid-foley-491199', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/matt-carasiti-35645', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/cole-hamels-10996', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/sonny-gray-14979', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/daniel-norris-18409', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/antonio-senzatela-34707', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/cole-hamels-10996', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/wade-miley-11462', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/eric-lauer-259699', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-clevinger-34646', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/daniel-norris-18409', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/michael-wacha-15848', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/chris-archer-17449', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/hyun-jin-ryu-14542', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/chris-archer-17449', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-clevinger-34646', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/ross-detwiler-11370', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/ross-detwiler-11370', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/antonio-senzatela-34707', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/chris-archer-17449', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/michael-wacha-15848', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/danny-duffy-11224', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/shaun-anderson-1026728', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/matt-carasiti-35645', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/daniel-norris-18409', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/ross-detwiler-11370', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/danny-duffy-11224', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jhoulys-chacin-10924', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/ross-detwiler-11370', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/lance-lynn-11292', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/chris-archer-17449', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/matt-carasiti-35645', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-fiers-13170', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-soroka-276320', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/sean-reid-foley-491199', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/danny-duffy-11224', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/john-means-551356', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/daniel-norris-18409', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/eric-lauer-259699', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/antonio-senzatela-34707', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/hyun-jin-ryu-14542', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/sean-reid-foley-491199', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/cole-hamels-10996', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/ross-detwiler-11370', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-fiers-13170', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/michael-wacha-15848', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/sonny-gray-14979', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/chris-archer-17449', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/lance-lynn-11292', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-fiers-13170', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/antonio-senzatela-34707', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/elieser-hernandez-42486', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/john-means-551356', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/hyun-jin-ryu-14542', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/yonny-chirinos-38039', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jhoulys-chacin-10924', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/antonio-senzatela-34707', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/shaun-anderson-1026728', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/danny-duffy-11224', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/yonny-chirinos-38039', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/wade-miley-11462', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/merrill-kelly-16363', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/anibal-sanchez-10997', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-fiers-13170', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/vincent-velasquez-18877', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/merrill-kelly-16363', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/anibal-sanchez-10997', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jose-berrios-35029', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/vincent-velasquez-18877', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/sonny-gray-14979', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/ross-detwiler-11370', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/noe-ramirez-17480', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-clevinger-34646', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/wade-miley-11462', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/yonny-chirinos-38039', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/lance-lynn-11292', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/matt-carasiti-35645', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/cole-hamels-10996', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/daniel-norris-18409', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-clevinger-34646', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-soroka-276320', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/danny-duffy-11224', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/anibal-sanchez-10997', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/shaun-anderson-1026728', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-clevinger-34646', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-clevinger-34646', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/hyun-jin-ryu-14542', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/matt-carasiti-35645', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/sonny-gray-14979', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/michael-wacha-15848', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/eric-lauer-259699', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/michael-wacha-15848', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/wade-miley-11462', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/anibal-sanchez-10997', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jhoulys-chacin-10924', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/noe-ramirez-17480', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-fiers-13170', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/cole-hamels-10996', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/antonio-senzatela-34707', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/matt-carasiti-35645', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/eric-lauer-259699', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/michael-wacha-15848', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/sonny-gray-14979', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/merrill-kelly-16363', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/noe-ramirez-17480', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-clevinger-34646', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/eric-lauer-259699', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jacob-degrom-17652', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/daniel-norris-18409', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/anibal-sanchez-10997', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/lance-lynn-11292', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/merrill-kelly-16363', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/merrill-kelly-16363', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/michael-wacha-15848', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/lance-lynn-11292', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jhoulys-chacin-10924', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/sean-reid-foley-491199', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/ross-detwiler-11370', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/sonny-gray-14979', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/michael-wacha-15848', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/cole-hamels-10996', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/hyun-jin-ryu-14542', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/cole-hamels-10996', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/wade-miley-11462', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-fiers-13170', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/matt-carasiti-35645', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/eric-lauer-259699', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/vincent-velasquez-18877', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/elieser-hernandez-42486', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/sonny-gray-14979', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-soroka-276320', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/daniel-norris-18409', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-clevinger-34646', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jose-berrios-35029', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jose-berrios-35029', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/noe-ramirez-17480', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jose-berrios-35029', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/sean-reid-foley-491199', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-clevinger-34646', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jose-berrios-35029', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/vincent-velasquez-18877', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/john-means-551356', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/hyun-jin-ryu-14542', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/hyun-jin-ryu-14542', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/john-means-551356', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/sean-reid-foley-491199', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/yonny-chirinos-38039', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/sean-reid-foley-491199', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/danny-duffy-11224', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/john-means-551356', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/cole-hamels-10996', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/ross-detwiler-11370', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/matt-carasiti-35645', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jhoulys-chacin-10924', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/yonny-chirinos-38039', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/vincent-velasquez-18877', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-soroka-276320', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/sean-reid-foley-491199', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-fiers-13170', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/shaun-anderson-1026728', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/yonny-chirinos-38039', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/shaun-anderson-1026728', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/noe-ramirez-17480', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/lance-lynn-11292', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/vincent-velasquez-18877', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/yonny-chirinos-38039', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/sonny-gray-14979', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/chris-archer-17449', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/wade-miley-11462', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/anibal-sanchez-10997', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/shaun-anderson-1026728', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/danny-duffy-11224', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/lance-lynn-11292', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/anibal-sanchez-10997', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/noe-ramirez-17480', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jose-berrios-35029', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/elieser-hernandez-42486', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jhoulys-chacin-10924', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/lance-lynn-11292', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/merrill-kelly-16363', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jose-berrios-35029', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/anibal-sanchez-10997', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/hyun-jin-ryu-14542', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jhoulys-chacin-10924', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/noe-ramirez-17480', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/john-means-551356', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-fiers-13170', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/vincent-velasquez-18877', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-fiers-13170', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/danny-duffy-11224', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/merrill-kelly-16363', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/noe-ramirez-17480', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/elieser-hernandez-42486', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-soroka-276320', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/elieser-hernandez-42486', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/ross-detwiler-11370', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/elieser-hernandez-42486', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/vincent-velasquez-18877', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/daniel-norris-18409', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/danny-duffy-11224', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/daniel-norris-18409', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/eric-lauer-259699', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/shaun-anderson-1026728', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-soroka-276320', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/eric-lauer-259699', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jacob-degrom-17652', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/shaun-anderson-1026728', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jacob-degrom-17652', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/sean-reid-foley-491199', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/wade-miley-11462', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/noe-ramirez-17480', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jacob-degrom-17652', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/wade-miley-11462', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/elieser-hernandez-42486', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jacob-degrom-17652', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/lance-lynn-11292', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/yonny-chirinos-38039', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/matt-carasiti-35645', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/wade-miley-11462', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/elieser-hernandez-42486', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/john-means-551356', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jacob-degrom-17652', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/john-means-551356', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jose-berrios-35029', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jose-berrios-35029', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jacob-degrom-17652', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/merrill-kelly-16363', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/chris-archer-17449', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/jacob-degrom-17652', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-soroka-276320', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/mike-soroka-276320', 'https://rotogrinders.com/players/yonny-chirinos-38039']
```